# Using "like%" in the RShiny code with Oracle DATABASE

Tags: r, oracle

If i create this input:

```
checkboxGroupInput("ordemlista", "Tipo de Ordem:",
                                           choices=list('LQ','LQR', 'LQX')
                               ),
```

To filter using the choises with LIKE condition, how can I do?

```
df <- dbGetQuery(
  connection_reportUser,
  query <- glue(
"select cod_ordem_producao
from pla.cod_ordem_producao
WHERE cod_ordem_producao like 'input$ordemlista'%      <----- DOES NOT WORK
")
```

In my SQL code, I can do it directly, that way: (for example)

```
select cod_ordem_producao
from pla.cod_ordem_producao
WHERE cod_ordem_producao like 'LQR%'
```

But using GLUE package with the INPUT, it just not work.

Does someone know how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the single quote should be after the % sign. Here, you can use sprintf to get the input value in the query.

```
query <- sprintf(
"select cod_ordem_producao
from pla.cod_ordem_producao
WHERE cod_ordem_producao like '%s%%'",input$ordemlista
)
```

Note: the %% is to tell sprintf that we want use treat the % after %s as a regular string with no other functions or meanings.